# Is there any filter to trigger as soon as media is uploaded to post or page?

Tags: filters

I am new to WordPress. I want to change attributes of image when uploaded to page or posts. Is there any filter for it?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Which attributes do you want to modify? Also, it is not clear if you want to modify attributes when the image is inserted to post editor or when the image is uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use, `image_send_to_editor` . Here is the link, [image_send_to_editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/image_send_to_editor/)